# Extracting every single image (e.g. as .png or other formats) from a .tvips file using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a .tvips file containing some TEM images (1024 x 1024) pixel acquired sequentially. I wonder if there would be a way to extract them from this kind of file as *classic* .png, .tif ... file images.

I saw that the liberTEM package allows to deal with .tvips files. However It is not clear to me how access to every single image/dataset contained in the .tvips file and save it as .png, .tif ... file.

Comment: If you would like folk to assist you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them. So, presumably you know what a `.tvips` file is so you could a) share one via Dropbox or Google Drive, b) share a link to a definition of the format...

Comment: I am not familiar with the tvips format. But one of the first results when Googling it suggests [tvipsconverter - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tvipsconverter/). Perhaps that could help.